# Func delegate to declared method

Tags: c#, generics, func

Having these two methods declared in a non-generic class, which share the same signature:

```
    private TypeResolverResult<T> TryRetrieveFromReusable<T>(TypeResolverConfiguration<T> typeResolverConfiguration) where T : class 
    {
        return null;
    }

    private TypeResolverResult<T> BuildNew<T>(TypeResolverConfiguration<T> typeResolverConfiguration) where T : class
    {
        return null;
    }
```

How can I create a delegate that represents these methods' signature?

I can't seem to get it, I tried:

```
    private Func<TypeResolverConfiguration<T>, TypeResolverResult<T>> _typeResolveFunc;
```

But obvious this does not work because the class is non-generic and I can't change that.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is more or less what I need:

```
    public class Manager : ATypeResolver, IManager
    {
        private neeedDelegate;


        public Manager(RuntimeConfiguration runtimeConfiguration, IList<RepositoryContainer> repositories)
        {
            if (runtimeConfiguration.WhatEver)
            {
                neeedDelegate = TryRetrieveFromReusable;
            }
            else
            {
                neeedDelegate = BuildNew;
            }
        }

        public override TypeResolverResult<T> Resolve<T>() where T : class
        {
            //Want to avoid doing this:

            if (runtimeConfiguration.WhatEver)
            {
                TryRetrieveFromReusable(new TypeResolverConfiguration<T>());
            }
            else
            {
                BuildNew(new TypeResolverConfiguration<T>());
            }

            //and have just this

            neeedDelegate<T>(new TypeResolverConfiguration<T>());
        }

        private TypeResolverResult<T> TryRetrieveFromReusable<T>(TypeResolverConfiguration<T> typeResolverConfiguration) where T : class 
        {
            return null;
        }

        private TypeResolverResult<T> BuildNew<T>(TypeResolverConfiguration<T> typeResolverConfiguration) where T : class
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you trying to use it?  It is hard to have a generic type parameter if nothing is generic.  Methods can be generic even if the type is not because the caller defines the type.  However, fields and properties cannot be generic unless the containing type is generic.

Comment: @cadrell0 The methods are generic but the class is not generic, and they have a defined constraint: class

Comment: @cadrell0 Yes you right, back to the beginning.

Comment: @Marco How were you hoping to use this field? Maybe what you need would be better served by using local variables? Another option, though not a great one, would be to store it as a non-generic `object`, and cast at run time (e.g. in generic methods on your non-generic class).

Comment: @TimS. Basically I have a configuration object, and based on the setting within that object I need to create two different code paths. The other option is to use conditionals every some code in the class runs, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** From what I can see, an approach like this should work, as long as `ATypeResolver` has a `where T : class` on `Resolve<T>`:

```
public class Manager : ATypeResolver, IManager
{
    private bool tryRetrieveFromReusable;

    public Manager(RuntimeConfiguration runtimeConfiguration, IList<RepositoryContainer> repositories)
    {
        this.tryRetrieveFromReusable = runtimeConfiguration.WhatEver;
    }
    public override TypeResolverResult<T> Resolve<T>()
    {
        var typeResolver = tryRetrieveFromReusable ? (TypeResolver<T>)TryRetrieveFromReusable : BuildNew;

        return typeResolver(new TypeResolverConfiguration<T>());
    }
}
```

This uses a custom delegate type (a `Func` like you have should work too):

```
public delegate TypeResolverResult<T> TypeResolver<T>(
    TypeResolverConfiguration<T> typeResolverConfiguration) where T : class;
```

If you like, you can move the `var typeResolver = ...` line to its own method, to separate the logic and allow you to use it from more than just `Resolve`. If you did that, Resolve might be as simple as: `return GetTypeResolver<T>()(new TypeResolverConfiguration<T>());`.

Comment: You still can't do that because the containing class is not generic.  Where does the `T` come from?

Comment: @cadrell0 from "where T : class;"

Comment: @TimS. I was hoping to use the Func delegate, but you're right, I'll have to create my own, I just thought I was missing something. Thanks

Comment: @Marco This has the same problem as your original attempt.  This just is a little bit more code and a little cleaner looking.

Comment: @cadrell0 Not sure if I am following you, because that solves my problem, I was just trying to avoid the need to create other delegates.

Comment: @Marco in your non-generic class, declaring a field like `private TypeResolver<T> _typeResolveFunc;` will not compile. (unless you've got a class somewhere named `T`, which to put simply: you should not)

Comment: The methods are fine by themselves; using `Func<TypeResolverConfiguration<T>, TypeResolverResult<T>>` or `TypeResolver<T>` is fine. What's not fine is using `T` in a context that has no `T` defined, such as a non-generic class's field.

Comment: @TimS of course, cadrell0 spotted that right away, so I'm pretty much in a death end here.

Comment: @TimS. but since Resolve is called multiple times, the conditional that I want to avoid is there. I don't want to have to check for any configuration detail inside that method, only at the constructor.

Comment: The condition is evaluated just once with my solution: in the constructor, `WhatEver` is read and the result is stored. Even if this is a long process, the result of the constructor is the storage of a simple boolean. It's true that the local `bool` is reread, but that's as trivial as rereading a `TypeResolver<T>` field (like you were trying to do at first).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand exactly how generics work.  I'll give a quick overview, but read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx).

When you have a generic class

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Bar {get; set;}
}
```

And you use it something like this

```
Foo<int> intFoo = new Foo<int>();
Foo<string> stringFoo = new Foo<string();
```

At compile time, the compiler will detect the two usages of the generic type.  It will create a type of each usage.  So your assembly will have types that look something like this (no not exactly, but let's play pretend so that we humans can understand).

```
public class FooInt
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooString
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And it will replace all uses of `Foo<int>` with `FooInt` and `Foo<string>` with `FooString`

Now if we have a non-generic class with a generic method

```
public class Foo
{
    public T GetBar<T>() { ..... }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
int x = foo.GetBar<int>();
string s = foo.GetBar<string();
```

The compiler will generate

```
public class Foo
{
    public int GetBarInt() { ..... }
    public string GetBarString() { ..... }
}
```

And it will replace `GetBar<T>` with `GetBarInt` and `GetBar<string>` with `GetBarString`

But fields aren't like that.  If you have a class that looks like so

```
public class Foo
{
    public T Bar;
}
```

You cannot do this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar<int> = 1;
foo.Bar<string> = "test";
```

The compiler just doesn't understand that.  I'm not an expert on the internals, but my guess is that because this points to a place in memory, the compile cannot generate the generic usages at compile time.

But the point I am trying to make is this.  Generics are not some magical "I don't need to specify the type" feature.  They are hints to the compile that say "I am going to do this same thing multiple times, I want you to generate the code for me."

Comment: I do exactly know how they work, what I do not know, is if it is possible to set a constraint into the definition of a delegate usage hence my question. Back in my java days, circa 2004 and when the mighty Sun Java forum was still up, I had the best possible answer to what generics are, I can't remember the exact name, I believe his nickname was Jonathan. But thanks anyway :)